# Too many indices for array when using mask

Tags: python, mask

I am getting the subject IndexError, but I don't know why as I checked the *shapes* of the arrays involved and they match.

First, in my code I create an array that I transpose for processing, so that I'd get colmuns for *year_rec*, *event*, and *value*. Resulting in array of 369563 rows & 3 columns.

```
maxevent_arr = np.array([year_rec, event, value])
maxevent_arr = maxevent_arr.transpose()
print("maxevent_arr[1590:1595]= \n", maxevent_arr[1590:1595])
print("shape(maxevent_arr)= ", maxevent_arr.shape)
```

which yields:

```
maxevent_arr[1590:1595]= 
 [[1.964e+03 3.000e+01 5.000e-01]
  [1.964e+03 3.000e+01 3.000e+00]
  [1.964e+03 3.000e+01 4.500e+00]
  [1.964e+03 3.000e+01 7.500e+00]
  [1.964e+03 3.000e+01 8.800e+00]]

shape(maxevent_arr)=  (369563, 3)
```

Then I create a mask called *mask_yr* which identifies those indices with the year 1964. Later I reshape this mask to the same number of elements and 1 column, as one might expect.  I do this because without this step I was a shape of (369563,) i.e. without an identifiable column..

```
mask_yr = maxevent_arr[:, 0] == 1964
mask_yr = np.reshape(mask_yr, (maxevent_arr.shape[0], 1))
print('mask_yr[:5]: \n', mask_yr[:5])
print("shape(mask_yr) = ", mask_yr.shape)
```

which yields:

```
mask_yr[:5]: 
 [[ True]
 [ True]
 [ True]
 [ True]
 [ True]]
shape(mask_yr) =  (369563, 1)     # this looks ok.
```

Lastly, I apply the same mask to all the columns to grab the respective values for each row.

```
mask_rain = maxevent_arr[:, mask_yr]
print('mask_rain[1590:1595]: \n', mask_rain[1590:1595])
```

This is where I get the IndexError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\1_Earthfx\Python\hourly_rain\rain_analysis.py", line 150, in <module>
    mask_rain = maxevent_arr[:, mask_yr]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Any idea on what this is about? Dimension 0 for *maxevent_arr* matches that from *mask_yr*....

Comment: Where you have `maxevent_arr[:, mask_yr]`, in your own words: how many dimensions do you expect `maxevent_arr` to have? When you index an array with that many dimensions with `[:, x]`, where `x` is a mask, how many dimensions do you think `x` should have? (Why?) Now, how many dimensions does `mask_yr` have?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reshape the boolean mask, as it has the required dimensions.
So this line of code is not needed:

```
mask_yr = np.reshape(mask_yr, (maxevent_arr.shape[0], 1))
```

And, of course, the change below is also required:

```
mask_rain = maxevent_arr[:, mask_yr]   # to be changed to

mask_rain = maxevent_arr[mask_yr, :]
```

@Karl Knechtel  you see, no need for know-it-all and useless comments!